# Using VBA in Excel to assign title to date ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I've searched and not found any results that help me with this specific query.

I want to use VBA to create a new field in a spreadsheet that assigns a title based on a date range.

I have a spreadsheet with dates from October 6 to yesterday, and I want to be able to create a new column to indicate the sales cycle of each row in Excel.

What I can't figure out is how to set the code to check and assign dates between sales cycles.

For reference, this is what I have right now, which works fine if there are only two dates to work with:

```
Sub salescycle_date()

Dim msheet As Worksheet
Dim sc1 As Date
Dim sc2 As Date
Dim sc3 As Date

Set msheet = ActiveSheet

sc1 = "06/10/2015"
sc2 = "24/11/2015"
sc3 = "24/01/2016"

Range("AJ1").Select
ActiveCell = "sales_cycle"

For i = 6 To msheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  Select Case msheet.Cells(i, 33)
  Case Is < sc2
  msheet.Cells(i, 36) = "Sales Cycle 1"
  Case Is >= sc2
  msheet.Cells(i, 36) = "Sales Cycle 2"
  End Select

  Next
  MsgBox "done!"

End Sub
```

Any tips on how to set the code so that it can recognize sales cycle 2 as being in between the start of SC2 and SC3, and then have SC3 as a separate option?

Comment: What is the outcome you're getting, and what is the outcome you're supposed to get?

Comment: The outcome that I get is all dates before 24/11/2015 are marked as 'Sales Cycle 1' and dates from the 24th onwards (to yesterday) are marked as 'Sales Cycle 2'.

However, I don't know (and can't find online) a way to set the dates between 24/11/2015 and 24/01/2016 as 'Sales Cycle 2' and the dates from 24/01/2016 to yesterday as 'Sales Cycle 3'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
Sub salescycle_date()

Dim msheet As Worksheet
Dim sc1 As Date
Dim sc2 As Date
Dim sc3 As Date

Set msheet = ActiveSheet

sc1 = "06/10/2015"
sc2 = "24/11/2015"
sc3 = "24/01/2016"

Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell = "sales_cycle"

For i = 2 To msheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  Select Case msheet.Cells(i, 1)
  Case Is >= sc3
  msheet.Cells(i, 2) = "Sales Cycle 3"
  GoTo ExitSelect
  Case Is >= sc2
  msheet.Cells(i, 2) = "Sales Cycle 2"
  Case Is < sc2
  msheet.Cells(i, 2) = "Sales Cycle 1"
  End Select

ExitSelect:
  Next
  MsgBox "done!"

End Sub
```

Here, I've reversed the conditions of select cases with an additional GoTo statement.

Comment: Thanks @Bhagyesh! That works perfectly. If I want to update the code for future sales cycles, would I add an additional GoTo statement?

Comment: Never mind, I just tried it out and it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help.